# Sampling distribution with intelligence quotient

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

The Intelligence Quotient of adults follows normal distribution with mean $m = 100$ and standard deviation $σ = 10$.

Consider a sample of 27 adults and calculate the probability for the IQ of the sample to be less than 98.

What I've tried so far:

$Z = \frac{\bar X - m}{σ/\sqrt{n}} = \frac{98 - 100}{19.245} = 0.1039$.

So from z-score tables the required probability is $0.555$.

I don't know if it's correct and I also need some explanation on what exactly we compute by this.
I am very new to statistics and distributions.

Thank you.

Comment: Various points:  $10/\sqrt{27}$ should be smaller than $10$ , while $98 - 100$ should be negative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have all the tools, this is a more formal answer.
Start from
$$ \mathbb{P}(\bar X \le 98) $$
and then renormalize exactly as you did
$$ \mathbb{P}\big(\sqrt{n}\frac{\bar X - m}{\sigma} \le \frac{98-100}{19.245} \big). $$
Now you know that the right-hand side follows a $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ law by properties of Gaussian distribution. So the desired probability is just
$$ \mathbb{P}\big(U \le \frac{98-100}{19.245} \big), $$
where $U$ follows the $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ law.
You can read it in a table or compute it numerically to find the result.I find 0.4589973 but you probably need to double check (but be aware that your computation for $Z$ gives -0.1039 and not 0.1039).

Comment: Thank you very much. In which cases do we use the formula $\big(Z = \frac{X-m}{σ} \big)$?

Comment: $\frac{\bar X - m}{\sigma \sqrt{n}} $ or $\frac{\bar X - m}{\sigma /\sqrt{n}}$ here?

Comment: Thanks @Henry, I edited the post

Comment: @Sal.Cognato I am not sure what is your question, but the idea is that we have table for $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, not for the other distributions, and that it's enough because we can normalize, hence we consider the normalised random variable $Z = \frac{X-m}{\sigma}$.

Comment: I suspect the $19.245$ is too big and the $-0.1039$ too small in magnitude